# How to make HTTPs Request call with Certificate in Rest-Assured

Tags: rest-assured, client-certificates, pfx

I need to make HTTPS Get call with certificate in Rest Assured. I had .pfx certificate, I changed it to .p12 format. And my code is:

```
          SSLConfig config = null;
  
          try {
              keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
              keyStore.load(
                      new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\Certificate.p12"),
                      "password".toCharArray());
  
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              System.out.println("Error while loading keystore >>>>>>>>>");
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
  
          if (keyStore != null) {
  
              org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory clientAuthFactory = new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(keyStore, "password");
  
              // set the config in rest assured
              config = new SSLConfig().with().sslSocketFactory(clientAuthFactory).and().allowAllHostnames();
```

After running it respond with Error 403.